# How can a background thread modify the UI in between Activity loads in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, background

I have a download process that runs in the background, and updates the UI with progress (a ListView adapter). It works fine until I leave the activity and come back. After loading the activity again there is a "new" ListView object that is not the same one that is bound to the BG download process. How can I structure my code so that the background process can always talk to the ListView in my activity?

The specific line that does this is:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here is the shell of the Download class:

```
public class Download
{
   }
   protected void start() 
   {

      TransferManager tx           = new TransferManager(credentials);
      this.download                = tx.download(s3_bucket, s3_dir + arr_videos.get(position), new_video_file);


      download.addProgressListener(new ProgressListener() 
      {
        public void progressChanged(final ProgressEvent pe) 
        {
          handler.post( new Runnable() 
          {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
              if ( pe.getEventCode() == ProgressEvent.COMPLETED_EVENT_CODE )
              {
                Download.this.onComplete();
              }
              else
              {
                Download.this.onProgressUpdate();
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
   }

   protected void onProgressUpdate()
   {
      this.download_status         = "downloading";
      Double progress = this.download.getProgress().getPercentTransfered();
      Integer percent  = progress.intValue();
      //Log.v("runnable", percent + "");

      downloaded_data.edit().putInt(position+"", percent).commit();


      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

Comment: Use Android Async task
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is simply "no". There's no simple way to find/keep the reference to a ListView in a destroyed/recreated Activity.

One way you can get around this is to use [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). You can broadcast progress intents, and have the Activity register/deregister from those intents in onCreate() and onPause().

Another (arguably easier) hack you can do it is to persist the state (along the lines of what you're doing with downloaded_data.edit()), and have a thread in your Activity that regularly polls this state and updates the ListView accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can save data of listview in file, then in function onCreate callback to take it. Using File may be a solution. Once your Activity is destroyed, all datas are lost

Answer (score 0):

Make tasks *detachable*, like an Executor service placed in a component that is always there between Activity changes:

1. Use a Service: clients can connect to it and request what tasks are running etc.
2. Implement Application class and let it hold references to tasks that are running, exposed via a static field.